# Java8 to Java7 - Migrate Comparators

Tags: java-8, migration, java-7, comparator

I'm having troubles understanding how to "migrate" a simple Comparator in Java7.

The actual version I'm using in Java8 is like:

```
 private static final Comparator<Entry> ENTRY_COMPARATOR = Comparator.comparing(new Function<Entry, EntryType>() {
    @Override
    public EntryType apply(Entry t) {
        return t.type;
    }
})
        .thenComparing(Comparator.comparingLong(new ToLongFunction<Entry>() {
            @Override
            public long applyAsLong(Entry value) {
                return value.count;
            }
        }).reversed());
```

But in build phase I get this error:

```
static interface method invocations are not supported in -source 7
```

How can I migrate the same comparator to Java7? I'm googling and searching for solution but the only thing I can think of, is to implement my own class as a Comparator interface implementation.

But If I go down that road, how can I apply both "comparing", "then comparing" and "reverse" in the same "compare" method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would use `guava`, it has `ComparisonChain`, I *think* it can handle this for you

Comment: by the way, you didn't share your java 7 code version tried, which gave the error you've mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the logic in a single `compare` method:

```
public int compare (Entry one,Entry two) {
    int result = two.getType().compareTo(one.getType());
    if (result == 0) {
        result = Long.compare(two.getCount(),one.getCount());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that the reversed order in achieved by swapping the order of the compared `Entry` instances.

Comment: To reverse the result just prepend a ´-´ before the result during returning.

Comment: @Flown That might not work. A comparison method is allowed to return *any* integer value. But the negation of Integer.MIN_VALUE is itself, so this doesn't achieve the effect of inverting the sense of the comparison in this case.

Comment: @StuartMarks Ah you're perfectly right. Maybe one should apply the `Math::signum` to avoid such error and negate the result. (I was assuming proper  -1, 0, 1 values).

Answer (score 6):

Even your java-8 version can be made a lot shorter and easier to read with:

```
Comparator.comparing(Entry::getType)
          .thenComparingLong(Entry::getCount)
          .reversed();
```

With `guava` (java-7 compatible), this looks a bit more verbose:

```
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry left, Entry right) {
        return ComparisonChain.start()
                .compare(left.getType(), right.getCount(), Ordering.natural().reversed())
                .compare(left.getCount(), right.getCount(), Ordering.natural().reversed())
                .result();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a `Comparator<Entry>` the java 7 way, afterward, you can chain the default methods as you can do in java 8, but without using lambda expressions or method references as a parameter :

```
private static final Comparator<Entry> ENTRY_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Entry>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry left, Entry right) {
        return left.type.compareTo(right.type);
    }
}
.thenComparingLong(new ToLongFunction<Entry>() {
    @Override
    public long applyAsLong(Entry entry) {
        return entry.value;
    }
})
.reversed();
```

The code above is compiled with `-source 1.7`.